# .htaccess & error pages - Stay on page and don't redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, apache2, custom-error-pages

This seems very simple. `ErrorDocument` redirection to another page:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 400 /err/e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /err/e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /err/e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /err/e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /err/e=500
```

But the problem with these custom error pages is that the browser actually redirects to the page `/err/e=404` instead of just showing its content. When not using custom error pages, the URL in the browser stays the same, thus allowing the user to correct the URL without having to type it again.

**Question:** How to create custom error pages that do **not** alter the URL and leave it like `domain.tld/nonexistantfile` ?

**Background:** Debian Wheezy, Apache2 and PHP are used.

**Update** posting the entire .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 400 /err/e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /err/e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /err/e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /err/e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /err/e=500

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ favicon.ico [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*) downloads/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) js/$1 [L]

RewriteRule index.php(.*) index.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*=.*) index.php?controller=$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*=.*) index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?controller=$1 [L]
```

The last part enables URL's like `/home` or `page1/page2/param=123`

Comment: No these `ErrorDocument` do not make browser redirect to `/err/e=404`. You may have some conflicting rule causing this. Can you post your full .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a rule to avoid rewrite for real files/directories like this:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /err/e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /err/e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /err/e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /err/e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /err/e=500

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^=]+=.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^=]+=.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I also removed some redundant rules.

Comment: The redundant stuff you removed is great! But it still redirects to `/err/e=...` and I even tested from a virtual environment that didn't see the site yet in order to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Test in a different browser and also test it in a Firebug and see what redirects you get in Net tab. Also could it be that `/err/e=400` is doing redirect via code?

Comment: Calling a non-existent file actually causes a `302 Found` error, thus it redirects. It should actually cause a 404 error. The `/err/e=404` page responds with a normal 200.

Comment: Ok comment out all `ErrorDocument`except 404 one. Then create a file called `error.php` with just this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` And change 404 handler to `ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404` and then rerun the test in Firebug

Comment: That's odd. Even after restarting all XAMPP modules and installing a new browser in a freshly installed virtual machine, the old rules (/err) still apply. What is wrong here?

Comment: You mean you remove `ErrorDocument 404 /err/e=404` line and it is till in effect? Could it be some rules in Apache config? Are you sure you're running Apache only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63305/discussion-between-devils-child-and-anubhava).